# Use of verb 'help'

Tags: verbs

Which of the following sentences are correct and why?

> 1. Could you please help my son get the job?
> 2. Could you please help my son in getting the job?

Comment: You may wish to have a look at our sister site for [ell.se].

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences could be correct if you changed the *could* in the second sentence to *would*

*Would* and *could* are both used to make a polite request, however *would* references what someone said in the past about a future action. [More on Would vs Could here](https://blogs.transparent.com/english/english-could-vs-would/).

Thus, *getting* would fit just as correctly as *get* if second sentence changed *could* to *would*

Comment: But 'getting' is not in past tesnse here.